# How can get Mathjax.js with ANCII.js to show appended json data as proper formulae?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, math

I am  doing  a  mathematics  quiz  and  trying  to  use  json  to  store  questions    and Mathjax.js with ANSCII.js  to  render  complex  math expressions.

For  example
 {

```
    "question": "`[[a,b],[c,d]]`=",
                "choices": [
                    "1",
                    "0",
                    "-1",
                    "2"
                ],
 "correctAnswer": "B",
"hint": "......"

            },
```

I have  a  function  appending  question data like...

/*MyLib.x is  a  variable  which  selects  current  question  in  array  of  questions  and  is  incremmented  with  progress  from  question  to  question*/

```
var choiceOne=$('<p>').append('A.'+$exam[MyLib.x].choices[0]);
var choiceTwo=$('<p>').append('B.'+$exam[MyLib.x].choices[1]);
var choiceThree=$('<p>').append('C.'+$exam[MyLib.x].choices[2]);
var choiceFour=$('<p>').append('D.'+$exam[MyLib.x].choices[3]);

var currentQuestion=$('<h3>').append($exam[MyLib.x].question);


$('#options').find('p').remove().hide();
$('#optionOne').fadeIn(250).append(choiceOne);
$('#optionTwo').fadeIn(250).append(choiceTwo);      
$('#optionThree').fadeIn(250).append(choiceThree);
$('#optionFour').fadeIn(250).append(choiceFour);
```

But  when  appended  the  data  only  shows  what  is  between ""  not  as  formulae  as  hoped do  I  need  to  stringify  it  or  some  js  method?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution,

```
MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
```

Ensures the text  is  rendered  after  being appended.